# What should i write in jenkins file?

Tags: java, jenkins, automation, jenkins-pipeline

I have an automation project written in Java, using Junit, and I'm trying to create my new Jenkins job pipeline.
I've created the pipeline and a new Jenkins file, but I don't know what this file should contain.
I need to -

1. build the project
2. Run the tests **by category** (I don't want to run
   all the test in one job)
3. Deploy

I've found this one in Jenkins documentation

```
pipeline {
    agent any

    stages {
        stage('Build') {
            steps {
                echo 'Building..'
            }
        }
        stage('Test') {
            steps {
                /* `make check` returns non-zero on test failures,
                * using `true` to allow the Pipeline to continue nonetheless
                */
                sh 'make check || true'
                junit 'pom.xml'
             }
        }
        stage('Deploy') {
            steps {
                echo 'Deploying....'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But I got this message:
"Test reports were found but none of them are new. Did leafNodes run?"

So how do I make it work? and how can I specify an exact category to run?

Comment: Why are you trying to deploy even if the make fails? (And why are you trying to use make with Java anyway?)

Comment: IDK, I took this example from the Jenkins pipeline documentation

Comment: Do you have an instance of maven in youyr jenkins ? Or can you use docker agents ?

Comment: I think I do have an instance of maven in my Jenkins...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of things you will need to setup first. Like jdk , maven, git credentials. Then your pipeline will looks something like this.

```
   pipeline {

  agent {
        node { 
            label 'the label of your agen or have "any" if you didnt specidy one'
        }
    }
  environment {
      //maven home as it is configured in Global Configuration
       mvnHome = tool 'maven'

       
    }
    
 options{
    // remove older builds and artifacts if they exceed 15 builds
    buildDiscarder(logRotator(numToKeepStr: '100', artifactNumToKeepStr: '100'))
    //add the time stamp to the logs
    timestamps()
 }

   
   
   stages {
    stage("Git CheckOut") {
      steps {
        script{
        //CheckOut from the repository
        def scmVars = checkout([$class: 'GitSCM', 
        branches: [[name: 'master']], //here you can enter branch name or SHA code
        userRemoteConfigs: [[credentialsId: 'credential that  you set for you git here', 
        url: "your git url here"]]]) 
        }
      }

    } 
    
    stage('Build Artifacts') {
        steps {
        sh "echo Packaging the artifacts!"
        //packaging the project
        sh "${mvnHome}/bin/mvn clean package  "
        //archiving the artifacts after the build
        sh "echo Archiving the artifacts!"
        archiveArtifacts 'target/*.war' // you can deploy to nexus if you setup nexus
        
        }
    }

    stage('Unit Test') {
        steps {
        //running the unit tests
        sh "${mvnHome}/bin/mvn clean test"
        }
        
    }


     
     
        stage('Transfer war file to Servers') {
            steps {
                sshagent(['agent name that was setup in your server where you want to deploy artifacts']) { 
                sh "echo Trasnfering files to servers!"
                //copy war file  servers
                    sh 'scp -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no $projPath/target/your war file /your server path'

                }
            }
        }
    
   }
   
   
    post {

        always {
            sh "echo Jenkins Job is Done"

        }
        success {
            sh "echo Sending Success Email!"
        }
        failure {
            sh "echo Sending Failed Email!"
          
        }
    }
   
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer! I have some questions though. 1) How can I found my git credentialId? i googled it and didn't found any answer. maybe its a git token? 2) in the tests step can I add this: clean test -e -f /home/omgili/jenkins/automation/pom.xml -Dgroups=categories.regression ? 3)What is the label and where can I defined the label?

Comment: Ok, so I've tried this but I removed the credentials cause I set them in Jenkins. and I removed the stage('Transfer war file to Servers') cause I didn't know what to write there... and I got this message: WorkflowScript: 34: Undefined section "stage" @ line 34, column 5.
       stage('Build Artifacts') {
WorkflowScript: 46: Multiple occurrences of the stage section @ line 46, column 5.
       stage('Unit Test') {
WorkflowScript: 46: Undefined section "stage" @ line 46, column 5.
       stage('Unit Test') {
WorkflowScript: 1: Missing required section "stages" @ line 1, column 1.

Comment: The code I shared is based on some pre-configuration that you need to do. For example you need to have jdk configured in your global configuration also you need maven configuraed in the same place. For the git , you will need to have it added into your global configuration . but for that you will need to have git plugin first. I will advice you to go through some youtube videos to configure each section then you can use my code and modify it as per your need.

Comment: Thank you, i will check if i can find something on youtube. Do I have any way to contact you for private questions?

Comment: sorry , but i cant share my info on this platform. If you face any issues just right up a msg here and I ll get back to you. Or if you like to share your email address i can send you an email.